# How can I have dynamic input inside the react router element?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I just encountered a problem with the `react-router` `element`:

```
import Home from '../../views/newssandbox/home/Home'
import RightList from '../../views/newssandbox/right-manage/RightList'
import RoleList from '../../views/newssandbox/right-manage/RoleList'
.....

const LocalRouterMap = {
  "/home": Home,
  "/user-manage/list": UserList,
  "/right-manage/role/list": RoleList,
  "/right-manage/right/list": RightList,
  ...
}
```

I want my code to work as this

```
<Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
<Route path='/user-manage/list' element={<UserList />} />
<Route path='/right-manage/role/list' element={<RoleList />} />
```

How should I change this one?

```
backRouterList.map(item => {
  {/* console.log(item.key) */}
  <Route path={item.key} key={item.key} element={LocalRouterMap[item.key]} />
})
```

Comment: Hi, just FYI in case you missed it or hadn't taken the [tour] yet, there are 100% completely optional actions you can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) your questions to help curate content on the site. Welcome to SO, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of route path-component pairs:

```
const LocalRouterMap = {
  "/home": Home,
  "/user-manage/list": UserList,
  "/right-manage/role/list": RoleList,
  "/right-manage/right/list": RightList,
  ...
}
```

When mapping the array you will need to first create a valid local React component variable and render it out on the `Route` component's `element` prop ***as JSX***.

Example:

```
backRouterList.map(item => {
  const Component = LocalRouterMap[item.key];
  return (
    <Route path={item.key} key={item.key} element={<Component />} />
  );
})
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-have-dynamic-input-inside-the-react-router-element]

You could optimize this a bit by moving the JSX part to the `LocalRouterMap` object.

```
const LocalRouterMap = {
  "/home": <Home />,
  "/user-manage/list": <UserList />,
  "/right-manage/role/list": <RoleList />,
  "/right-manage/right/list": <RightList />,
  ...
}
```

Then you can just pass the element.

```
backRouterList.map(item => (
  <Route
    path={item.key}
    key={item.key}
    element={LocalRouterMap[item.key]}
  />
))
```

Comment: hi! grateful for answering my question. I tried both ways, but still can't work... make me confused.  I have <Route path="*" element={<NoPermission/>}/> below what I put in the question, the router all go to the no permission one...

Comment: @SongY Can you edit your post to include all relevant code as part of your [mcve]? For example, what is `backRouterList` that is being mapped? What does "the router all go to the no permission one" mean?

Comment: @SongY I copied your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-have-dynamic-input-inside-the-react-router-element-4c9g9z) and applied my solution and it appears to function as I expected. Feel free to fork this sandbox and see if you can copy in more of your code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: it works! tysm!! @Drew Reese